# Unable to use OneWayToSource binding in a Silverlight application

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, data-binding, binding

I'm implementing a Silverlight 5 application, using framework .NET 4.0.
I need to use the OneWayToSource binding but unfortunately it doesn't appear in the propositions.

[image: OneWayToSourceProblem]

I tried to know if it was [due to the framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or the silverlight version which seems not to be the case.

Do you have any piece of information that might help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not available in [Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). You consulted the wrong page (full .Net).

[Edit] You can simulate it with a `TwoWay`-Binding and a `ValueConverter` that discards any input in its `Convert` method:

```
public class DiscardingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(...)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

[UnsetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)